# Problem with camera - completely black image

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting

My camera appears to work: makes a noise as you depress the shutter. However only a completely black photo is actually taken. In fact no photo will even show up in the digital screen.  Any one else had a similar situation?

Comment: In order to answer your question you need to provide more information. What specific model? Does the camera write anything to the memory card? If so what? What does the EXIF info of any file written to the card say?

Comment: The shutter could be stuck...

Comment: Replace the batteries?

Comment: Can you post a sample here?

Comment: The inside of your lens cap looks black when it's on the lens.

Comment: Was it working before, or is this a new (to you) camera? Iso setting way too low?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest explanation for your problem is that someone forgot to remove the lens cap.

[image]

The [article](http://www.thephoblographer.com/2014/05/07/photographer-forgets-remove-leica-m-lens-cap-shoots-10-perfectly-black-frames/#.U3kgHlfwpDQ) at the phoblographer.com
And the [video](http://video.nhl.com/videocenter/console?id=100982).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, boy...

You have some possibilities here:

- lens cap on.
- the rear screen is disabled - You didn't mention the model of the camera but usually there exists in the menus a "Review time" option which has different values including 0 (zero)/OFF.
- stuck shutter

Hunt the cause by taking out the memory card from the camera (you have a card in it, isn't it?) an put it on a card reader. Alternatively you can use the camera as a 'card reader' by simply connecting it to the computer.

There are photos on the card? (usually these are in a subfolder of the DCIM folder)

If not, then you must ask a more knowledgeable friend, or, most probably, take it to a technician.

If yes, download/copy the photos on a directory of your choice. Have a look.

The photos are black?

...btw, can you post a sample here?

If yes, check your lens cap. :-) ...or any other thing which might obstruct the light path.

If not, IOW the photos are ok showing what you expect, then simply the rear screen is disabled.